# Magento 2 : Error when importing customers

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2.2, customer-attribute

When trying to import Customers from the backend, Data validation is OK
but when I click on import button, the page gets stuck on please wait for loader and I get the error :

See the logs below

> Apr 24 16:20:01 web9 ool www: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call
>   to a member function getBackendModel() on null in
>   /var/www/staging-vhosts/timberland.co.za/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Import/Customer.php:442#012Stack
>   trace:#012#0
>   /var/www/staging-vhosts/timberland.co.za/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Import/Customer.php(517):
>   Magento\CustomerImportExport\Model\Import\Customer->_prepareDataForUpdate(Array)#012#1
>   /var/www/staging-vhosts/timberland.co.za/vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Import/AbstractEntity.php(640):
>   Magento\CustomerImportExport\Model\Import\Customer->_importData()#012#2
>   /var/www/staging-vhosts/timberland.co.za/vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Import.php(441):
>   Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\AbstractEntity->importData()#012#3
>   /var/www/staging-vhosts/timberland.co.za/vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Import.php(412):
>   Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import->processImport()#012#4
>   /var/www/staging-vhosts/timberland.co.za/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\ImportE in
>   /var/www/staging-vhosts/timberland.co.za/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Import/Customer.php
>   on line 442

Can you please advise as to what could be the cause of this issue, is there any way I can get all customer attribute, so I can see what attribute is causing this.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried importing it locally and debug it?

Comment: I have tried importing locally but i'm getting the same error, seems to be something to do with customer attributes but i don't know where to start looking into this

Comment: ok. and have you tried debugging it?

Comment: How do i do that?
I'm still new to Magento 2

Comment: xdebug. just how you debug any other php applications. there are plenty tutorials outthere that teach you how to configure xdebug